# What is the ClassResolvers do in netty?

Tags: netty

it is a argument in `ObjectDecoder` class. it has method like `weakCachingConcurrentResolver`. So What is the caching all about? Is it like a share memory created ahead to buffer received bytes from network? Why does it call weak caching?